# Why can't I set a multiple select dropdown with this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiple-select

opts is an array ["1","2"]. The select options are not selected. The dropdown is a bootstrap multiselection plugin. What am I missing here?

```
var data = {};
data.action = "get-form-data";
data["account-id"] = localStorage.getItem("account-id");
ajax('post', 'php/enablers.php', data, formDataSuccess);
function formDataSuccess(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $("#min-rating").val(data.MinRating);
    debugger;
    var opts = data.AcceptedMedia.split(",");
    $.each(opts, function(inx,val){
        $('#accepted-media option[value=' + val + ']').attr('selected', true);        
    })
    $("#special-instructions").val(data.SpecialInstructions);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Writer's Tryst - Enablers Form</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/enablers.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.rateyo.min.css">
        <style>
            select {
                padding-bottom: 8px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container center_div">
            <img id="img-enablers" src="#" alt="images" />
            <form id = "form-enablers"  class="form-horizontal well">
                <h1>Enablers</h1>              
                <p>
                    <label for="form-type" class="fixed50">Form:</label>
                    <select id="form-type" name="form-type[]" class="btn  btn-outline" multiple="multiple" required>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="genres" class="fixed50">Genres:</label>
                    <select id="genres" name="genres[]" multiple="multiple" required>
                    </select><br/>
                </p>
                <p>For an explanation of the genres shown here, see <a target="_blank" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_genres">List of genres</a><br/></p>
                <p>
                    <label for="accepted-media" class="fixed50">Accepted Media:</label>
                    <select id="accepted-media" name="accepted-media[]" multiple="multiple" required>
                        <option value='1'>Mail</option>
                        <option value='2'>PDF File</option>
                    </select><br/>
                </p>
                    <label for="min-rating" class="fixed50">Minimum Rating:</label>
                    <div id="min-rating"></div>
                <p> <label for="special-instructions" class="fixed50">Special Instructions:</label>
                    <textarea id ="special-instructions" name="special-instructions"></textarea>
                </p>
                <p class="thumbnail">For a limited time, enablers can use this site for <span style="color: #f00; font-weight:bold">FREE</span>. We reserve the right to change this policy without notice.</p>
                <p id="recaptcha-elements"></p>
                <div class="form-group">    
                    <button type="submit" id="enablers-search" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block glyphicon glyphicon-search"> Search</button>
                </div>
                <input id="userid" name="userid" type="hidden" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <form id="writers-list">
            <p id="manuscript-request">To request a manuscript, click the checkbox beneath the thumbs-up icon.</p>
            <div id="table-list"></div>
            <div id="main" class="content"></div>

        </form>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.rateyo.js"></script>
        <script src="js/enablers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/recaptcha.js"></script>
    </body>                           
</html>
```

Comment: How about adding the HTML so we can be sure you are targeting the right  element?

Comment: I .posted the HTML

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/0obu9zqL/7/

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar - I wonder what the difference could be.

Comment: Maybe the returned JSON isn't what you expect. Why are you returning a comma-delimited string instead of a JSON array?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the `$.each` loop and see what the selector is matching.

Comment: My guess is there is perhaps some whitespace in the comma separated string after commas?

Comment: @Barmar  - this is what is displayed when I enter $('#accepted-media option[value=' + val + ']').attr('selected', true); in the console:   [<option value=​"1" selected=​"selected">​Mail​</option>​]. Are the brackets suspicious?

Comment: No they're not. jQuery objects are always shown as an array.

Comment: That looks correct. It's setting the `selected` attribute properly. Something must be unselecting it after the code runs. Try setting a "Break on attribute change" on the element, and see if it fires after the ajax code is done.

Comment: OK...reading question again problem is *"The dropdown is a bootstrap multiselection plugin"*. Means you need to work with that api or perhaps it will listen if you trigger `change()`

Answer (score 0):

Since `val()` of `<select multiple>` is array... it is simpler to just set the `<select>` value instead of looping the options

`$('#accepted-media').val(opts)`

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/h94nmawh/)**</kbd>

Comment: This isn't quite the same. His code selects additional options, it doesn't unselect the others. Your code will unselect options.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. It still doesn't set the selected values. Any ideas on what could be going on here?

Comment: @Barmar I don't see that for that particular  select

Comment: @rontornambe does the element exist when code runs? Perhaps is ajax loaded? Or you forgot `document.ready`?

Comment: If needed can also merge existing values array

Comment: @charlietfl - yes, yes and yes. I put an alert in to ensure the element was found alert($('#accepted-media')..length) - it returned 1.

Comment: No idea unless something else changing it after or something wrong with `opts` ... whitespace perhaps?

Comment: How confounding. The console shows the correct array values - no whitespace.

Comment: Duplicate ID in page?  `alert($('[id="accepted-media"]').length)`

Comment: @charlietfl  - you got it. Thanks so much. There is a special command for setting selections with the bootstrap multiselection.  Please post an answer  so I can reward your efforts.

Comment: @rontornambe What do you mean? You are commenting on their posted answer.